# can I create non expiring tokens in OneDrive / Sharepoint?

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, odoo, onedrive

I created an API OneDrive Microsoft App to list folders and files in an odoo Database table. the client would like to send a onedrive link (field on this table) to the end customers to download the file. I did a python code following Microsoft Code Flow API requirements. However, the token keeps expires after one hour.

I tried many MS Azure API permissions such as File.Read, File.Read.All. I also read that I needed to give **Application permission** so I did, however, now I need Admin to Grant consent. Before I approach the "not so nice" IT department I would like to double check if I am on the right track or asking for the impossible:

- can I design an app to read from OneDrive or SharePoint and have the token *not* expire?
- If I get the IT department to grant Admin consent will I be able to get the none expiring tokens?
- does anyone have any suggestions or a work around?

I am using a Microsoft Account that belongs to a company so I am not admin and I it is not a home account.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online

Answer (score 2):

> can I design an app to read from OneDrive or SharePoint and have the
> token not expire?

No. Access token must have a expiry time. See [access token document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens).

> If I get the IT department to grant Admin consent will I be able to
> get the none expiring tokens?

No. Admin consent doesn't do such a thing.

> does anyone have any suggestions or a work around?

You can consider [Configurable token lifetimes in the Microsoft identity platform (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes). **Please note that only the admin of that tenant can set this**.

The detailed steps are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes).

Pay attention to the **Note** tip.

[image]

It means the above link only works for mobile and desktop clients. If you want to manage the lifetime of web browser sessions, use the [Conditional Access session lifetime feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime).

The [SharePoint Online blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/introducing-idle-session-timeout-in-sharepoint-and-onedrive/ba-p/119208) about configuring idle session timeouts for your reference.